# Theory for IF statement refactoring?

Tags: if-statement, boolean-logic, boolean-operations, boolean-algebra

There are some known rules, which refer to various combinations of IF statements (or if/else or switch/case statements etc). These rules can be used for refactoring.

Example 1:
"Nested IFs with single body can be always replaced by one IF with AND conditions."

```
if (a) {
  if (b) {
     doSomething();
  }
}
```

can be rewritten as:

```
if (a && b) {
  doSomething();
}
```

Example 2:
"Subsequent IFs with the same body can be always replaced by one IF with OR condition."

```
int i = 0;
if (a) {i = 1;}
if (b) {i = 1;}
```

can be rewritten as:

```
if (a || b) {i = 1;}
```

I'm sure there are many more similar rules. I would like to know if there is a known theory behind this, which gives generic pattern for creating such rules. I would like to see a list of other known rules. I think boolean algebra does not exacly handle this, because it uses mathematical syntax which does not exactly translate to programming syntax.

There are similar questions, which always ask about one rule or another. This question is completely generic, not about particular rules, but about the theory behind them.

Comment: 1) the codes samples in your example 2 are _not_ equivalent - if a and b are both true, in the first example `doSomething` will be called twice, in the second, once 2) the only thing that comes to mind is De Morgan's laws but that's a pretty limited subset of what it seems you're looking for

Comment: Consider taking a look at [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) too which will fomalises [DeMorgan's Theorm](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/de-morgans-theorem)

Comment: Updated the second example because of the side effect of calling the doSomething() twice, which was not the point.